# Is the matrix exponential for a given matrix $\mathbf{A}$ always the same?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-exponential

If I was given a matrix $\mathbf{A}$ and said to obtain the matrix exponential 
$$e^{\mathbf{A}t}=\Phi(t)\Phi(0)^{-1}$$
does this matrix $\mathbf{A}$ has only one matrix exponential? Or does it depend on the solution vectors obtained?

I am asking this, because I was solving a problem and the exponential matrix I obtained was different than the one in the instructor's solutions manual.  I don't know if this question has been asked here before, I tried looking it up but didn't find anything.

For example, I was asked to obtain the matrix exponential for
$$\mathbf{A}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 0 & 1 & 4 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

the answer I obtained was
$$e^{t}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2t & 4t^{2} +5t \\ 0 & 1 & 4t \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

however, the one in the solutions manual was
$$e^{t}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2t & 4t^{2} +3t \\ 0 & 1 & 4t \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Book looks correct, see: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=matrixexp+%7B%7B1t%2C+2t%2C+3t%7D%2C+%7B0%2C+1t%2C+4t%7D%2C+%7B0%2C+0%2C+1t%7D%7D. If you show your work, we can spot where the issue occurred (maybe just an algebra issue).

Comment: Yes, the matrix exponential is a function, so $\exp({\bf A} t)$ depends only on ${\bf A} t$.

Comment: @Moo You are correct. I did go over my solution again, it turns out that when I multiplied two matrices by each other, I multiplied $\Phi(0)^{-1}\Phi(t)$ instead of $\Phi(t)\Phi(0)^{-1}$... and that gave me the wrong answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\exp tA$ is a well-defined function of $tA$. It only depends on $tA$.

The Jordan Decomposition is
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1&2&3\\0&1&4\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix} 
=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0\\0&\frac12&-\frac3{16}\\0&0&\frac18 \end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix} 1&1&0\\0&1&1\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0\\0&\frac12&-\frac3{16}\\0&0&\frac18 \end{bmatrix}^{-1}
$$
Next
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1&1&0\\0&1&1\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}^n
=\begin{bmatrix} 1&\binom{n}{1}&\binom{n}{2}\\0&1&\binom{n}{1}\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\exp t\begin{bmatrix} 1&1&0\\0&1&1\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}
=e^t\begin{bmatrix} 1&t&\frac{t^2}2\\0&1&t\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\exp t\begin{bmatrix} 1&2&3\\0&1&4\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}
&=e^t\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0\\0&\frac12&-\frac3{16}\\0&0&\frac18 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 1&t&\frac{t^2}2\\0&1&t\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0\\0&\frac12&-\frac3{16}\\0&0&\frac18 \end{bmatrix}^{-1}\\[6pt]
&=e^t\begin{bmatrix} 1&2t&3t+4t^2\\0&1&4t\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$$
So my answer agrees with the book.

Without seeing your work, I cannot comment on where the problem might be.

Comment: Thank you so much. I made a mistake in my solution I wrote $\Phi(0)^{-1}\Phi(t)$ instead of $\Phi(t)\Phi(0)^{-1}$ which is why I got the wrong answer.

Answer (score 2):

Although there are many ways to compute it, the exponential of a matrix is unique. If you’re solving a differential equation, though, you might come up with a different partition of the arbitrary constants of integration from the book solution. In this case, however, it looks like you’ve made an error in computing this matrix exponential.

No doubt you’ve already found that the only eigenvalue has geometric multiplicity one, so let $N=A-I$. The matrices $N$ and $I$ commute, therefore $e^{tA}=e^{t(I+N)}=e^te^{tN}$. In addition, $N^3=0$, therefore $$e^{tA}=e^t\left(I+tN+\frac{t^2}2N^2\right).$$ Without computing $N^2$ you can see from this that the element in the upper-right corner must be of the form $3t+ct^2$, so your calculation went awry somewhere.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understood now.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the matrix exponential is uniquely defined by the exponential series. As every matrix commutes with the identity, you get
$$
\exp((I+B)t)=e^t\exp(Bt)=e^t(I+Bt+\frac12B^2t^2+\frac16B^3t^3+...)
$$
Here $B=\pmatrix{0&2&3\\0&0&4\\0&0&0}$ is nilpotent, $B^3=0$, the same for all higher powers, so that the exponential series only consists of the first three terms,
$$
\exp(At)=e^t\left(\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1}+\pmatrix{0&2&3\\0&0&4\\0&0&0}t+\frac12\pmatrix{0&0&8\\0&0&0\\0&0&0}t^2\right)
=e^t\pmatrix{1&2t&3t+4t^2\\0&1&4t\\0&0&1}
$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. That was helpful.